# Hostname is not displayed appropriately on command prompt & syslog messages

Tags: linux, command-prompt, hostname

I try to set my hostname as **0.6.0.07252014** but when i see on command prompt and syslog messages, it is not getting displayed appropriately.

Entered hostname: 0.6.0.07252014

Command prompt output: root@0~$

I want output like: root@0.6.0.07252014~$

Can anyone tell me how to do it.

hostname file:

```
prompt> cat /etc/hostname
0.6.0.07252014
```

syslog file output:

cat /var/log/messages:

Output:  Jul 28 15:55:27 0 user.info ...

Expected Output: Jul 28 15:55:27 0.6.0.07252014 user.info ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe it is because "\h" is in your `PS1` environment variable, and it will take 0 as your hostname, replace it with "\H", which will display the full hostname.[Bash $PS1 Generator2.0](https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html)

Comment: Now it's working for command prompt. But the same is happening with my /var/log/messages. Can you help me on this?